# ASP.NET MVC Core default layout page not loading if I navigate to any razor page in Identity area e.g login, register etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am currently working on an ** MVC Core project using .Net8 preview**. Everything on the project works fine except the pages included after scaffolding identity. i.e Login, Register etc. When I navigate to login\Register page for example, **the default layout of my app doesn't load. Meaning my navbar and footer is not displayed.** Instead a blank navbar is displayed with nothing but the project name and Login/Register button at top. But  on all the razor views everything works find.

What I have also noticed is that **if I try to edit the Login.cshtml page, the changes doesn't reflect on the UI.** (Not related to HotReload). Even if I clean, rebuild or restart visual studio, the changes don't reflect when login page is loaded. For example I modified this simple h2 on login.cshtml

From

`your text`

### Use a local account to log in.

To

`<h2>Use223 a local account to log in.</h2>`

Nothing happens. I don't know if the Account pages are being loaded from another location other than the folders in my project.

- I have tried scaffolding identity several times from several previous versions of the project, and end up with same issue.
- I have mapped razor pages in Program.cs file
  _ I have correctly specify the layout page in ViewStart file inside Accounts folder

`@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }`

What's even weirder is that if i add a breakpoint to the constructor in login page model, i never hit that breakpoint even though the login page loads. So in theory I don't think the pages are being loaded from the ones in my project. Otherwise I'll definitely hit the breakpoints set. I even deleted the entire Identity folder under areas. But the login page still loads.

Here is a link to my project

https://github.com/KenJanka/Bulky_Login_UI_Issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue. Turns out that the version of .Net 8 preview
i have installed requires at least visual studio 2022 17.6 preview 2. I was using vs 2022 17.5.5. After upgrading to 17.6 preview 6, the issue went away and scaffolding identity works perfectly now.

Comment: I am facing the exact issue but with .net 6, just updated VS but it didn't work, any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I think this is some issues because of the version of .NET and Visual studio not being compatible ( at least in my case ). If you recently updated your .Net framework version, check the release notes of the .NET version you have installed to see if it's compatible with your current version of VS. That is a good place to start. Or perhaps uninstall/reinstall your .net again or a higher version

Comment: @emilekeen I'm seeing exactly the same behavior. Everything works fine for a .NET 6 project using VS 17.7 with SDK 7 installed. But the same .NET 6 project using VS 17.8 with SDK 8 installed, it's as if the Pages aren't even there, and are being loaded elsewhere.

Comment: Same thing happening for me now.  Currently using .net core 8.0.3  VS 17.8.7 latest but any change I made for Login page or other identity scaffold pages are not reflecting.  Identity Area with the pages are there but not even the breakpoints getting hit.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have any code to work with, I will use generic theory.

When you are on MVC, you will notice that in the views/shared folder you can see a layout there.

The scaffolded Identity is all Razor pages that use a unique routing sequence. Some even come with their own layout page, and might even want their own DB COntext.

You can however confirm what is using what layout by going to their views. In each view page, there should be a "Layout" that accepts the Layout path.

The layout page is where the Navigation is typically stored. its default is mostly;

```
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

As for the login button, it is most times a partial view that is referenced from the layout page.

Comment: Yes all this info is correct. However, I have verified both the default layout (Views/Shared/_Layout) and the layout  that comes with scaffolded identity pages ( Identity/Pages/Account/Manage). Both are ok. And I have also mapped razor pages in program.cs file. What's even weirder is that if i add a breakpoint to the constsructor in login page model, i never hit that breakpoint even though the login page loads. So in theory I don't think the pages are being loaded from the ones in my project. Otherwise I'll definitely hit the breakpoints set. P.S. There's an attached link to the project