# ASP.NET MVC Core default layout page not loading if I navigate to any razor page in Identity area e.g login, register etc

Tags: .net, asp.net, model-view-controller, identity-management

I am currently working on an MVC Core project using .Net8 preview. Everything on the project works fine except the pages included after scaffolding identity. i.e Login, Register etc. When I navigate to login\Register page for example, the default layout of my app doesn't load. Meaning my navbar and footer is not displayed. Instead a blank navbar is displayed with nothing but the project name and Login/Register button at top. But on all the razor views everything works find.

What I have also noticed is that if I try to edit the Login.cshtml page, the changes doesn't reflect on the UI. (Not related to HotReload). Even if I clean, rebuild or restart visual studio, the changes don't reflect when login page is loaded. For example I modified this simple h2 on login.cshtml

From

```
<h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
```

To

```
<h2>Use223 a local account to log in.</h2>
```

Nothing happens. I don't know if the Account pages are being loaded from another location other than the folders in my project.

I have tried scaffolding identity several times from several previous versions of the project, and end up with same issue.
I have mapped razor pages in Program.cs file _ I have correctly specify the layout page in ViewStart file inside Accounts folder

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
```

Comment: exact dupe [ASP.NET MVC Core default layout page not loading if I navigate to any razor page in Identity area e.g login, register etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76163033/asp-net-mvc-core-default-layout-page-not-loading-if-i-navigate-to-any-razor-page)